# React: OnChange for drop down return me the entire <select></select> tag

Tags: reactjs, drop-down-menu

I am working with react and I have a dropdown menu which is generated like that:

```
Select a user : <select defaultValue={'DEFAULT'} onChange={this.handleFilter}><option value="DEFAULT" disabled>-- select an gangster --</option>{ddUsers}</select>
```

ddUsers:

```
let ddUsers = this.state.users.map(user => <option key={uuid.v4()} value={user}>{user.name}</option>)
```

And here is my users array:

```
users : [
    { name: 'All',    key : uuid.v4()}, 
    { name: 'Koko',   key : uuid.v4()},
    { name: 'Krikri', key : uuid.v4()},
    { name: 'Kéké',   key : uuid.v4()}
  ]
```

My problem is that when I want to use the event.target it return me the entire select tag (here the output of console.log(event.target):

```
<select>
​<option value=​"DEFAULT" disabled selected>​-- select an gangster --​</option>
​<option value=​"[object Object]​">​All​</option>​
<option value=​"[object Object]​">​Koko​</option>​ 
<option value=​"[object Object]​">​Krikri​</option>​
<option value=​"[object Object]​">​Kéké​</option>​
</select>​
```

where it should normally return me only the user.
here is my handleUser (which displays me select tag above):

```
handleFilter = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target);
}
```

I am lost on what I am missing. I have something similar and it's working perfectly.

Comment: Hi! I think you forgot about the value. event.target.value

Comment: Actually with this return event.target.value just return me '[object Object]' and the event.target.value.name 'undefined'

Comment: well a value is still only a string value what should be passed in inside options, you are passing in an object (namely user), why not just pass in `user.key` and map afterwards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is a key/value at select value, but unfortunately, it does not work.
Maybe you'll need to use another component like React-select or use JSON.stringfy() and JSON.parse()

I have made an abstraction code using JSON methods.

```
const uuid = {
  v4() {
    return Math.random();
  }
};

const users = [
  { name: "All", key: uuid.v4() },
  { name: "Koko", key: uuid.v4() },
  { name: "Krikri", key: uuid.v4() },
  { name: "Kéké", key: uuid.v4() }
];

function App() {
  const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState("");

  function parseSelected(event) {
    const valueToParse = event.target.value;
    const itemSelected = JSON.parse(valueToParse);
    setSelected(itemSelected);
    return;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <select name="any" id="any" onChange={parseSelected}>
        {users.map(user => (
          <option key={user.key} value={JSON.stringify(user)}>
            {user.name}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
      <p>Selected name: {selected.name}</p>
      <p>Selected key: {selected.key}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

the reason is Option HTML interface accepts only DOMString as a value.
You can see the docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement)

Comment: Marked this one as the answer because you simply highlighted the fact that I can only use a string as value, and then I've worked around this one and now I have this line for my function: (event.target.value === this.state.users[0].key) ? (this.setState({selected:this.state.users})) : (this.setState({selected: [(this.state.users.find(user => user.key ===event.target.value))]}));
        and it seems to work good for my purpose, thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this.. This allows for flexibility so you can use this `<select>` component anywhere, using any object with any property.. (using @CarlosQuerioz answer, you'd always have to use an object with a `name` key)

Parameter meanings:

- **data**: array you are wanting to use as options for select
- **value**: the key from your data property that you want to display
- **placeholder**: placeholder value (not selectable)
- **defaultOption**: default selected option (more on this below)
- **onSelectChange**: event that is fired when selection changes

*How we handle `defaultOption`*:

- If you pass in an array of objects to `defaultOption` we will select the first object in that array, and use the specified `value` key to determine the value to be shown
- If you pass in an object, we will show the specified `value` key

To demonstrate the `defaultOption`, uncomment each of these values in the example below, you'll see what I mean.

```
    const users = [                 // If this was your `data` object
      { name: "Karkar", key: 1 },
      { name: "Koko", key: 2 },
      { name: "Krikri", key: 3 },
      { name: "Kéké", key: 4 }
    ];

      <MySelect
        data={users}
        value="name"                // Must be a valid key that your objects have
        onSelectChange={handle}
        defaultOption={users[0].name} 
        //defaultOption={users[1]}  // Would display 'Koko' by default
        //defaultOption={users}     // Would display 'Karkar' by default
      />
```

***EXAMPLE:***

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;
const { render } = ReactDOM;

function MySelect({ data, value, defaultOption = "", onSelectChange, placeholder = "Select an option" }) {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(defaultOption);
  
  const handleOnSelectChange = selection => {
    onSelectChange && onSelectChange(selection);
  }

  const handleChange = event => {
    let sel = data.find(d => d[value] === event.target.value);
    setSelected(sel);
    handleOnSelectChange(sel);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof selected === "object") {
      let val = selected.length > 0 ? selected[0] : selected;
      setSelected(val);
      handleOnSelectChange(val);
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <select value={selected[value]} onChange={handleChange}>
      <option value="" disabled>
        {placeholder}
      </option>
      {data && data.map((itm, indx) => (
        <option key={indx} value={itm[value]}>
          {itm[value]}
        </option>
      ))}
    </select>
  );
}

const users = [
  { name: "Karkar", key: 1 },
  { name: "Koko", key: 2 },
  { name: "Krikri", key: 3 },
  { name: "Kéké", key: 4 }
];

function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState();

  const handle = selectedUser => {
    setUser(selectedUser);
  };
  
  return (
    <div>
      <MySelect
        data={users}
        value="name"
        placeholder="Please make a selection"
        onSelectChange={handle}
        //defaultOption={users[0].name}
        //defaultOption={users[0]}
        defaultOption={users}
      />
      {user && <pre>{JSON.stringify(user, null, 2)}</pre>}
    </div>
  );
}

render(<App />, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.9.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.9.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```